# Почему в этом коде дважды освобождается память?

Tags: c++, память

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int* data;
    A() {
        data = new int[1999]{ 0 };
        cout << "HELLO" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "BYE" << endl;
        if (data != nullptr) {
            delete[] data;
            data = nullptr;
        }
        
    }
};

A returnA(bool i) {
    A a;
    A b;

    if(i){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
    
}
int main() {
    bool i = true;
    A d = returnA(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Program stdout:
HELLO
HELLO
BYE
BYE
BYE

Program stderr:
double free or corruption (!prev)

Comment: Потому что у вас нет корректных копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания.

Comment: Сосчитайте сколько раз вызывается конструктор копии.